# What is the difference between class X and class X extends Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer, prototype, javascript-objects

I know that:

- if you declare `class X {…` then, `X`'s constructor *must not* have a call to `super`, but
- if you declare `class Y extends Object {…` then `Y`'s constructor *must* contain a `super` call.

Are there any other semantic differences between the two?  Are there any observable differences between `X` and `Y` or `X.prototype` and `Y.prototype`—other than the class and function bodies (e.g., the value of `String(X)` vs. `String(Y)`)?

Comment: What is your interest in doing `class Y extends Object` in the first place? Or did you just ask this out of curiosity? Interesting question.

Comment: `Y` will have all own methods + methods from extended class. Meanwhile `X` will have only own methods. It's common OOP class extend mechanism. Also you usually do `class Y extends Z` not directly `extends Object`. And then `Z` has some basic logic for all classes

Comment: @Justinas, I think you miss the point here. In JavaScript all objects have `Object.prototype` in their prototype chain (except when you use `Object.create(null)` or something like that)

Comment: @trincot Yes, I know. Assuming `Object` is some kind of other class, not literal Object

Comment: @trrincot: I mean literally `Object`.  If I had meant some arbitrary class I would have not used the name of a built-in class.

Comment: @matt-browne: I'm working on a project that uses JavaScript very dynamically—extensively redefining inheritance chains during development on a persistent runtime, like one might in Smalltalk or CLOS.  I'm specifically considering proposing to tc39 that `super` calls should be permitted in the constructor of classes not initially declared as `extends <X>`, so that if you subsequently give the class another superclass using `Object.setPrototypeOf` things will still work as expected.  Limitations like this are one reason we've avoided using ES6 class syntax.

Comment: @cpcallen, I know. I think your comment to me was really intended for Justinas, right?

Comment: @cpcallen, I read your comment to matt, and understand what you mean. I just want to point out that JavaScript performance can get bad when you change prototypes. It is a killer for optimisers. See also the notice at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Comment: @trincot: we're already taking a 1000x performance hit by running our code [in an interpreter](https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/docs.html), so I'm not too worried about that.  Also, AFAICT, that notice is unnecessarily alarmist, at least WRT V8.  Yes: mutating the prototype chain of many objects at runtime is going to have some cost, but it's not noticeably worse than any other changes to the 'shape' of an object.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the rule that *"Y's constructor must contain a super call"* is only true when you actually *define* a custom constructor. You can however define `Y` without explicit constructor.

As you will have seen, `X.prototype` is an `instanceof X`, and `Y.prototype` is an `instanceof Y`. By defining a constructor (a "class"), you always implicitly create a (fresh) prototype object that has its `constructor` property set to that constructor. So obviously, `X.prototype != Y.prototype`.

But, going one level up in the prototype chain, you immediately find `Object.prototype`, meaning that the prototype chains for instances of `X` and `Y` merge immediately. All of the following prints "true":

```js
class X {}

class Y extends Object {}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(X.prototype) === Object.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Y.prototype) === Object.prototype);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(X.prototype).constructor === Object);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Y.prototype).constructor === Object);
```

There remains a difference in the prototype chain of the *constructors* (so not of the constructed objects or prototype objects, but of the function objects themselves); there is an extra level in the chain of `Y`, which represents `Object`. Again, all this prints "true":

```js
class X {}

class Y extends Object {}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(X) === Function.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Y)) === Function.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Y) === Object); // Object is missing in the proto chain of X
```

Comment: Oh yes, good point about `Y.__proto__` being `Object` rather than `Function.prototype`.